# How to cache the entire active record model from inside the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, activerecord

I essentially am wanting to move this inside of the vehicle model.

```
vehicle = @vehicle_cache.get(event[:mac_address])

unless vehicle
        begin
            vehicle = Vehicle.where('ID = ?',event[:mac_address]).first
        rescue
            vehicle = nil
        end
        @vehicle_cache.add(event[:mac_address],vehicle)
end
```

I'm thinking theres a way to override the internal find method?  But I'm not sure how to access the model from within itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Vehicle
  class << self
    def find_cached event_mac_address
      @vehicle_cache.get(event_mac_address) || \
        where('ID = ?', event_mac_address).first.tap do |vehicle|
          @vehicle_cache.add(event_mac_address, vehicle) if vehicle
        end
    end
  end
end
```

The above will define `find_cached` on `Vehicle` class. One should not interfere rails internals, like `find`, unless this in unavoidable.

Here we first try to get a cached value, then use `where` (note, that there is no need for `rescue` since `where` returns empty array, unlike `find`) and finally we add the newly found item to the cache.

Comment: Thanks. This is great.  Is it ok to use self.find_cached instead of class << self? I'm just not terribly familiar with meta programming.

Comment: Sure, both `self.find_cached` and `Vehicle.find_cached` are fine here.

Answer (score 1):

Use the rails cache in your model

```
def cached_mac_address_fetch(mac_address)
  Rails.cache.fetch([self, 'mac_address'], expires_in: 12.hours) do
    Vehicle.where('ID = ?', mac_address).first_or_create
  end
end
```

Comment: NOTE: if you use this and the model changes that you cached, you will need to bust the cache using Rails.cache.delete on the update of the model